# Unit test for Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm doing project using Google Cloud Endpoints (and Java). I wrote some unit tests for endpoints (validating method invocation results, etc.). But those tests don't find all bugs I have in code.

When I'm using generated Android library sometimes I have different variations of JSON bug's (like cyclic reference, missing setter for property or missing non-arg constructor).

Is there any EASY method to write those tests (or at least some boilerplate code with make writing those test easier)?

Comment: Can you send a reference to your code?

Comment: Unfortunately my original post was posted 3 years ago. I have no idea what was the source of those issue anymore.